# Error after updating to cordova 6.4.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor

I had a project running in cordova 6.3.1 and all was working fine.
After adding phonegap-plugin-push I started to have some issues

```
%% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0
%% Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for android                                  
%% Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 6.3.1, failed version requirement: >=6.4.0
%% Skipping 'phonegap-plugin-push' for ios
```

So I updated cordova to 6.4.0. (meteor add cordova:cordova@6.4.0)
Now I'm having these issues

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                           

   While adding plugin cordova@6.4.0 to Cordova project:                        
   Cordova error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "package". Please try       
   adding it again.
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not 
   apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the
   --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

/Users/diegodedieu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.tjodye++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/runtime/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
  throw error;
  ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you figured any solution?

Comment: No, i didn't. 
I removed cordova (meteor remove cordova:cordova) and run the app without installing any version of cordova, this way it worked again but with 6.3.1 version.